# Close the child of the parent of the parent

Tags: jquery

Hello i have an HTML Code like this

```
<div id="top">
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>toppanel</h1>
    <p>Content from toppanel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panelholder" id="ptop">
    <a class="open" href="#">open</a>
    <a class="close" href="#">close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more than on time. The only differnce is the id from the first div
My jQuery Code looks like this

```
// Expand Panel
$(".open").click(function(){
    $(#######).slideDown("slow");   
});
```

and my question is what i have to write for $(#######), if I want to slideDown the div with the class panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Expand Panel
$(".open").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('.panel').slideDown("slow");
});
```

You should read the API documentation on [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: Does closest check siblings too?  '.panel' isn't a parent of '.open'

Comment: .panel *is* a sibling of .open's parent, however. Which is what my code is doing.

Comment: When I saw it, you were using`.closest('div.panel')`

Comment: Erm, I haven't edited my answer and would never use `div.panel` because I generally keep my selectors tag-agnostic.

Comment: Strange.  Somehow, my comment got attached to the wrong answer, then.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(this).closest('top').find('.panel').slideDown("slow");
```

or

```
$(this).parent().prev().slideDown("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".open").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div.panel').slideDown("slow");   
});
```

This will find the parent of the open button with the panel class and slide it down, that way you don't have to worry about IDs or anything, just the open link being inside a panel.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to a simpler solution!

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".panel")
```

Have a look at the docs on [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: Changed it, this one is better!